# how to fix "Error: Cannot find module '/home/container/index.js'", I've tried everything

Tags: node.js

So the host that I use for my discord bot died so I downloaded all the code and tried hosting it on my PC. But I get the following error.

`Error: Cannot find module '/home/container/index.js`

> I've tried everything I can:

- updated nodejs
- reinstalled all my packages
- Changed package.json

How can I fix this?

Comment: please add some code so that we can understand what are you trying to do

Answer (score 1):

`Cannot find module` means you are trying to run non-existent file.
Ensure there is `index.js` in your working directory. If not,

1. Use `cd` to go to the directory where it is (usually it's `src` near the `package.json`)
2. Run `node ./index.js`

Answer (score 0):

Many time people have just the problem of command line to run file,
as windows and linux have
different syntax to run .js file

i.e.    node ./index.js      for linux
and     node .\index.js      for windows

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).